# What is the meaning of 101 and 110 errors in Zookeeper Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm using Zookeeper for Kafka. I'm using 3 Zookeeper clusters and 1 Kafka broker. In the zookeeper log i got errors 101 and 110. Error 101 is no node and error 110 is node exists.

**What is the meaning of 'node'?** Kafka Broker node or Zookeeper node?

Can anyone explain this, and how to solve it?
Thanks

Comment: more error logs please

Comment: @GuangshengZuo 
8/30/17 9:30:03 AM UTC session 0x35e2cc3817f0005 cxid 0x16e0 zxid 0x30000068b error -101
8/30/17 9:30:03 AM UTC session 0x15e2cc373e700bc cxid 0xb zxid 0x30000068c closeSession null
8/30/17 9:30:03 AM UTC session 0x35e2cc3817f0005 cxid 0x16e1 zxid 0x30000068d error -101

8/30/17 9:30:03 AM UTC session 0x35e2cc3817f0005 cxid 0x16e2 zxid 0x30000068e create '/brokers/topics/manis-tracker-lambda10300817/partitions,,v{s{31,s{'world,'anyone}}},F,1